# Algebra simplification in mathematical induction .

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was proving some mathematical induction problems and came through an algebra expression that shows as follows:

$$\frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6}  + (k + 1)^2$$

The final answer is supposed to be:

$$\frac{(k+1)(k+2)(2k+3)}{6}$$

I walked through every possible expansion; I combine like terms, simplify, factor, but never arrived at the answer.

Could someone explain the steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good idea for this sort of thing is to use [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=k%28k%2b1%29%282k%2b1%29/6%20%2b%28k%2b1%29%5E2%20=%20%28k%2b1%29%28k%2b2%29%282k%2b3%29/6&t=ff3tb01) to ensure that the two things are, indeed, equal.  In this case, they are, so we can spend some time looking to factor.

$$\begin{align}
\frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6}  + (k + 1)^2 &= \frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)  + 6(k + 1)^2}{6}\\
&= \frac{(k+1)(k(2k+1)  + 6(k + 1))}{6}\\
&= \frac{(k+1)(2k^2 +7k + 6)}{6}\\
&= \frac{(k+1)(k+2)(2k + 3)}{6}\\
\end{align}$$

EDIT: A helpful trick is the one I did in the step from line 1 to line 2: I factored out the $k+1$ immediately, rather than expanding the whole expression.  This makes it easier to deal with--most people have more practice factoring quadratics than cubics.

EDIT in response to comment:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)  + 6(k + 1)^2}{6} &= \frac{k\color{red}{(k+1)}(2k+1)  + 6\color{red}{(k+1)}(k+1)}{6}\\
&=\frac{\color{red}{(k+1)}\Big(k(2k+1)  + 6(k+1)\Big)}{6}
\end{align}$$

Comment: (k+1)(k(2k+1)+6(k+1))6 Could you please explain the second step?

Comment: @EvyLino Does that help?

Comment: Absolutely thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

First, let's write the expression as a sum of fractions with a common denominator.

$$\dfrac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6}  + (k + 1)^2 = \dfrac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6} + \dfrac{6(k+1)^2}{6}\tag{1}$$

Now expand $6(k+1)^2 = 6k^2 + 12k + 6\tag{2}$ and expand

$k(k+1)(2k+1) = k(2k^2 + 3k + 1) = 2k^3 + 3k^2 + k\tag{3}$

So now, $(1)$ becomes $$\dfrac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6} + \dfrac{6(k+1)^2}{6} = \dfrac{(2k^3 + 3k^2 + k) + (6k^2 +12 k + 6)}{6} $$ $$= \dfrac{\color{blue}{\bf 2k^3 + 9k^2 +13k + 6}}{6}\tag{4}$$

We can factor the numerator in $(4)$, or we can expand the numerator of our "goal"...

$$\frac{(k+1)(k+2)(2k+3)}{6} = \dfrac{\color{blue}{\bf 2k^3 + 9k^2 + 13k + 6}}{6}\tag{goal}$$

Comment: I did exactly everything you said. But never went well.

Comment: Ok am following...

Comment: Sometimes it's easier to work backwards to show that what you need is what you've got! (expand the goal, rather than factor the sub-goal)

Comment: @Amzoti Ayyyy, tell me!

Answer (score 4):

When we are given an expression of the form:

$$\frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6}  + (k + 1)^2$$

We should recognize that this is a case of simply adding fractions which can also be referred to as **rational expressions**.

The first thing I would suggest is to rewrite this as a case of adding fractions:

$$\dfrac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6}  + \dfrac{(k + 1)^2}{1}$$

Notice the **denominators** are different. In order to add fractions or rational expressions we need a **common denominator**. In this case, a common denominator could be 6.

What we will do is multiply the **numerator** and the **denominator** $\dfrac{(k + 1)^2}{1}$ by 6. We should also expand $(k+1)^2=(k+1)(k+1)$.

Rewriting the equation and having a **common denominator** of 6:

$$\dfrac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6}  + \dfrac{6(k + 1)(k+1)}{1(6)}$$

Now that we have a **common denominator** of 6 we can simply add the fraction and **simplify**.

$$\dfrac{k(k+1)(2k+1)+6(k + 1)(k+1)}{6} $$

$$=\dfrac{k(2k^2+3k+1)+6(k^2+2k+1)}{6} $$

$$=\dfrac{(2k^3+3k^2+k)+(6k^2+12k+6)}{6} $$

$$=\dfrac{2k^3+9k^2+13k+6}{6} $$

Factoring again:

$$=\dfrac{2k^3+9k^2+13k+6}{6} $$

Giving us our final answer simplified:
$$\boxed{\dfrac{(k+1)(k+2)(2k+3)}{6}}$$

Answer (score 3):

Well you can make life a lot easier for yourself by using the common factor of $k+1$. Taking this out, and also the factor of a sixth for neatness, your expression is
$$\frac 1 6 (k+1)(k(2k+1)+6(k+1))$$
Now you only have a quadratic to factor! $2k^2+7k+6$. You can use familiar methods to factor this as you seek.